# AbsoluteTiming gives vastly smaller results than it should

Tags: date-and-time, timing

I've been having some recurrent issues with [`AbsoluteTiming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTiming.html) and I would like to have a better idea of what causes them and whether they can be avoided.

More specifically, for some extended calculations, the timer results are much smaller than the actual time ellapsed, as measured by the clock on the wall. Here, for instance, is one example, which is just reading in some data from disk:

> [image]

The calculation's run time, as accurately recorded by the `DateString` calls, was close to six minutes, but `AbsoluteTiming` would like to have me believe that it's just that the time seemed longer because I was bored, and that it actually took about four times less than that. (In one recent egregious example, this time-contraction effect reported 19 seconds for a calculation that lasted close to six minutes.)

What is going on here? Is there something I can do to stop this from happening? I'm not *that* fussed about it but it's annoying that one important tool for keeping performance in check is failing this badly.

(I'm running MM v10.0.2 over Ubuntu 16.04, which is probably relevant.)

Comment: `AbsoluteTiming` is supposed to measure timing only for the kernel. The code you ran created also a large output which had to be processed by the frontend. That also took quite a while but was not taken into account by `AbsoluteTiming`. Suppress the output with a semicolon, and the timings should almost coincide. `Timing` measures both kernel and frontend timings.